# Ошибка связанная с tiktok_downloader на работает на сервере

Tags: python, python-3.x, deploy, tiktok

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in from tiktok_downloader
    import snaptik
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tiktok_downloader/init.py", line 1, in
    from .snaptik import snaptik, Snaptik
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tiktok_downloader/snaptik.py", line 10, in class
    snaptik(Session):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tiktok_downloader/snaptik.py", line 40, in snaptik
    def get_media(self) -> list[info_videotiktok]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Помогите ребят с этой ошибкой если кто-то встречался с ней я хотел создать телеграмм бота для скачивании видео из тик-тока без водяного знака но бот работает когда я ее запуская с помощью локалки но он мне выдает ошибку когда я ее деплою на сервер

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь использовать объект типа, как если бы это был список, но в Python типы не могут быть подписаны. Конкретная проблема заключается в строке `def get_media(self) -> list[info_videotiktok]:`, где вы указали возвращаемый тип списка `info_videotiktok`, но `info_videotiktok` оказывается типом, а не списком. Чтобы устранить эту ошибку, вам нужно изменить `list[info_videotiktok]` на список определенного типа.